# Spring MVC project initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a **Spring MVC project** with *Intellij Idea Ultimate v. 2021.1.3* in order to work on a course. Unfortunately, the instructor of the course uses an old version of *Eclipse*, so I'm trying to figure out how to create the same tree structure as him.

After I read the official documentation of JetBrains I tried to implement it with Spring Initialzr, tree structure isn't the same though. I also tried the method of picking the `webapp` archetype or adding framework support inside an empty project. None of these methods worked properly. In every case files such as WEB-INF and META-INF are missing. Is there any correct way to build an app for a Spring MVC project?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you to just create missing directories if it's only `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` missing. Looks like you already have a file structure you should follow so just create those so that they match.

Comment: The structure of an Spring Boot Project is *not* IDE dependend! But the IDEs display the structure a bit different. So do not try do modify the structure!

Comment: @Ralph So the approach of creating the MVC project with Initializr is correct? And you suggest not to modify the tree structure as I see in many other projects?

Comment: @michaelpnrs: yes: use the Spring Boot Initializer, yes: do not modifiy the structure - instead learn where IDEA display the files.